# System.NullReferenceException throw when build HasForeignKey

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, nullreferenceexception

I have code c# like this

```
    builder.Entity<EnPpTime>()
         .HasOne(a => a.EnPpTimeInMeta).WithOne(b => b.EnPpTime)
         .HasForeignKey<EnPpTimeInMeta>(e => e.Id);
```

when run the programe throw exception

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[2021-11-11T07:06:30.667Z]    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ForeignKeyAttributeConvention.UpdateRelationshipBuilder(IConventionForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder, IConventionContext context)
[2021-11-11T07:06:30.668Z]    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ForeignKeyAttributeConvention.ProcessForeignKeyAdded(IConventionForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
[2021-11-11T07:06:30.668Z]    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnForeignKeyAdded(IConventionForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder)
[2021-11-11T07:06:30.669Z]    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnForeignKeyAddedNode.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
[2021-11-11T07:06:30.669Z]    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.DelayedConventionScope.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
[2021-11-11T07:06:30.670Z]    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run()
[2021-11-11T07:06:30.670Z]    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run(IConventionForeignKey foreignKey)
[2021-11-11T07:06:30.671Z]    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionBatchExtensions.Run(IConventionBatch batch, InternalForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder)
[2021-11-11T07:06:30.671Z]    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.ReferenceReferenceBuilder.HasForeignKeyBuilder(EntityType dependentEntityType, String dependentEntityTypeName, Func`3 hasForeignKey)
[2021-11-11T07:06:30.672Z]    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.ReferenceReferenceBuilder.HasForeignKeyBuilder(EntityType dependentEntityType, String dependentEntityTypeName, IReadOnlyList`1 foreignKeyMembers)
[2021-11-11T07:06:30.672Z]    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.ReferenceReferenceBuilder`2.HasForeignKey[TDependentEntity](Expression`1 foreignKeyExpression)
```

How to fix this exception

Comment: Full reproduction code please

Comment: For security reasons, I could not post full code @CaiusJard

Comment: I think I should change e.Id to nullable. Is it correct

Comment: Oh, I didn't want the full code, I wanted a full reproduction - that's a code that we can literally paste into VS, hit Play and watch it go bang. Call the table and columns whatever you want; person:address will do so long as you can reproduce the problem. With a full reproduction we can either tell you what is wrong or confirm if you found a bug in EF..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like You're missing the
.HasPrincipalKey

in this case it will default to look for entityname suffixed "ID" in Your case "EnPpTimeID" which if it doesn't exist will fail

It is a very good idea when using entity framework always to use EntityTypeNameID for identity column in this case you will not have to explicitly defined the foreign and principal key

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known bug when there are [multiple one-to-one relationships between two entity types](https://issueexplorer.com/issue/dotnet/efcore/26162).

Calling `entity.HasOne(d => d.Parent).WithOne(p => p.Child)` **before** `entity.HasKey()` solved the problem for me. Read on for details:

I had the same problem using EF core 5 - .HasForeignKey() throws the said exception.
The DbContext was scaffolded. Scaffoling does not generate .HasPrincipalKey() for single-column foreign keys. Manually adding .HasPrincipalKey() did not fix the problem. My tables however had two 1:1 relationships. This means that the child table has 4 constraints: two foreign keys and two unique keys on the same columns as the FKs. The scaffolded code is:

```
    builder.Entity<Child>(entity =>
    {
        // 2 unique keys.
        entity.HasKey(e => e.ParentId);
        entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.OtherId, e.ParentId }).IsUnique();
        entity.Property(e => e.ParentId).ValueGeneratedNever();

        // 2 foreign keys.
        entity.HasOne(d => d.Parent).WithOne(p => p.Child)
            .HasForeignKey<Child>(d => d.ParentId);  // <---- Throws exception!
        entity.HasOne(d => d.Parent2).WithOne(p => p.Child2)
            .HasPrincipalKey<Parent>(p => new { p.OtherId, p.Id })
            .HasForeignKey<Child>(d => new { d.OtherId, d.ParentId });
    });
```

When I moved `entity.HasOne(d => d.Parent).WithOne(p => p.Child)...` **before** `entity.HasKey()` the problem disappeared. However, you should not modify generated code. I inherited the scaffolded DbContext and in the subclass wrote this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        // Bugfix:
        builder.Entity<Child>().HasOne(d => d.Parent).WithOne(p => p.Child);
        // You don't even need .HasForeignKey() here. It will be called inside base.OnModelCreating(). Duplicating .HasOne() and .WithOne() works fine.
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```